# Angular mouse leave not called with *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor, mouseenter, mouseleave

The (mouseleave) directive is not working, if it is generated with *ngFor:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of hoverdivs; index as i">
      <div style="background-color: grey" (mouseenter)="hoverdivs[i]=true" (mouseleave)="hoverdivs[i]=false">
      <p>Hoverable div #{{i}}</p>
      <p> hover status: {{item}} </p>
    </div>
  </ng-container>


  `,
})
export class App {
  hover:boolean;

  hoverdivs = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false]

  constructor() {
  }
}
```

[My working example can be seen here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mzbhISLPu03cs4uM0esz?p=preview): if you move the mouse fast enough, you can see that some of the divs "stuck" on hovering status.

[image: screenshot after fast mouse movement]

Is there a way to force mouseleave call?

Comment: sidenote: I know it can be solved with css :hover, but I need to have more complex calculations on hover events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not problem from `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`. It's because render from angular, see this [thread](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12874).

So the logic is, when `mouseenter` to the `div` (when slow) it actually call twice. You can debug it by function.

```
<div style="background-color: grey; height: 80px; margin-bottom: 15px;"
    (mouseenter)="fire($event, i)"
    (mouseleave)="fire($event, i)">
      Hoverable div #{{i}}
      hover status: {{hoverdivss[i]}}
    </div>

fire(e,key) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(key)
  }
```

even you put `e.stopPropagation();` it won't work cause angular will change `hoverdivs` and re-render template and eventually trigger `mouseenter` again. It will call twice.

here steps:

1. mouseenter
2. angular change value to true
3. trigger position last mouse
4. because same div trigger again mouseenter

In your case, you have problem fast mouse moving not change value `true` to `false` cause after angular done render, angular not call `mouseenter` again.

To solve this problem you should avoid template re-rendering.

Play [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/tEP5WTJWUdzhhgVtYeVE?p=preview).

Answer (score 2):

The `hoverdivs` array is used in the *ngFor, that means that angular will render all the divs every time it detects a change in the array.

When you `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`, you change the array, thus triggering the render of the divs. The div you moused over is now a **new** div.

You can avoid this simply by using something that angular won't detect changes, like an array of objects instead of an array of booleans.

Change `hoverdivs = [ false, false, false, false, false ]` 
to `hoverdivs = [ { status: false }, { status: false }, { status: false }, { status: false }, { status: false }, ]`

Angular will only detect a change in the array if you replace an entire object. It won't detect a change in the array if you just change a property of an object inside the array.

Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/nftBj9W4wKC2K5Se9xEr?p=info